# IdentityServer4 - missing claims from Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth, identityserver4

**TLDR;** In the context of using IdentityServer4

1. How do you get email address and hd claims from Google?
2. How do you get User.Identity.Name to be populated?

---

I have worked through the IdentityServer [quickstarts](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html) and have a working MVC client talking to a IdentityServer instance (apologies if using the wrong terminology). I am using External Authentication (Google) and do not have anything mildly complicated such as local logins / database etc. I am *not* using ASP.NET Identity. This is all working just fine.

I can successfully authenticate in my MVC app and the following code produces the claims in the screenshot below:

```
@foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
{
    <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
    <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
}
<dt>Identity.Name</dt>
<dd>&nbsp;@User.Identity.Name</dd>

<dt>IsAuthenticated</dt>
<dd>@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</dd>
```

[image]

### Questions:

1. I cannot retrieve extra claims (right term?) from Google. Specifically 'hd' or even 'email' - note that they don't show up in the claims in the above screenshot. How do I get the email address and hd claims from Google? What am I missing or doing wrong?
2. Note that the output of User.Identity.Name is empty. Why is this and how do I get this populated? This seems to be the only property of User.Identity that isn't set.

---

My setup is as follows - you can see the output of this as above:

### Client (MVC)

*In Startup.cs, ConfigureServices*

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = Configuration["App:Urls:IdentityServer"];
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Resource = "openid profile email";
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("domain");
    options.ClientId = "ctda-web";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
});
```

### Identity Server

*Client definition*

```
// OpenID Connect implicit flow client (MVC)
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ctda-web",
    ClientName = "Company To Do Web App",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    EnableLocalLogin = false,

    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:53996/signin-oidc" },

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:53996/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "domain"
    }
}
```

*IdentityResource definition*

```
return new List<IdentityResource>
{
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    new IdentityResources.Email(),
    new IdentityResource
    {
        Name = "domain",
        DisplayName = "Google Organisation",
        Description = "The hosted G Suite domain of the user, if part of one",
        UserClaims = new List<string> { "hd"}
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is amazingly unobvious: the sample code provided by IdentityServer4 works as long as you have the following configuration (in the Identity Server Startup.cs):

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients()
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers()); //<--- this line here
```

Why? Because AddTestUsers is doing a bunch of [the plumbing](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs) you need to do in your own world. The walkthrough implicitly assume you move to EF or ASP.NET Identity etc and make it unclear what you have to do if you aren't going to use these data stores. In short, you need to:

1. Create an object to represent the user ([here's a starter](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/TestUser.cs))
2. Create a persistance/query class([here's a starter](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/TestUserStore.cs))
3. Create an instance of IProfileService which ties this all together, putting in your definitions of a User and a UserStore ([here's a starter](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/TestUserProfileService.cs))
4. Add appropriate bindings etc

My IdentityServer Startup.cs ended up looking like this (I want to do in memory deliberately, but obviously not use the test users provided in the samples):

```
services.AddSingleton(new InMemoryUserStore()); //<-- new

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddProfileService<UserProfileService>(); //<-- new
```

Turns out Google does return email as part of the claim. The scopes in the code sample of the question worked.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to get email to be returned.

There are two ways to do this but they both require that you add the email scope to the initial request.  Just sending openId isnt going to work.

> Openid email

**UserInfo request**

Now when you get the access token back you can do

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token={access token}
```

Response

```
{
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "email": "xxxx@gmail.com", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "117200475532672775346", 
  "verified_email": true
}
```

Token Info Request:

Using the id token

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={token id}
```

response

```
{
 "azp": "07408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "07408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "sub": "00475532672775346",
 "email": "XX@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "at_hash": "8ON2HwraMXbPpP0Nwle8Kw",
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "iat": "1509967160",
 "exp": "1509970760",
 "alg": "RS256",
 "kid": "d4ed62ee21d157e8a237b7db3cbd8f7aafab2e"
}
```

As to how to populate your controller i cant help with that.

Comment: Thanks for replying DalmTo. Dumb question: is the line "options.Scope.Add("email");" not adding the email scope as you suggest? Or perhaps a better question is: can you help me understand the difference between what I have in my code samples and what you're suggested?

Comment: you are requesting email but you haven't made the call to userinfo endpoint.   to my knowledge Google dosent return the email as part of the claim embedded in the access token.  you will need to make the request to the endpoint to get this information